# WCF on Windows 7 why not working.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I new with WCF. I create wcf for server side printing scenario... I host wcf dll on console application. Below is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PrintBarcode)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my app.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CTIHandHeld.WCF.PrintBarcodeWcfServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior"
        name="CTIHandHeld.WCF.PrintBarcodeWcfServiceLibrary.PrintBarcode">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpBindingConfiguration"
          contract="CTIHandHeld.WCF.PrintBarcodeWcfServiceLibrary.IPrintBarcode" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:3518/PrintBarcodeService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TcpBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CTIHandHeld.WCF.PrintBarcodeWcfServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

That code works in windows XP.... Why its not work if i running it on windows 7? I running it as administrator and with firewall turned off.

The document only appear in print queue and disappear without warning or error... But printing not really happen.

Answer (score 1):

> That code works in windows XP.... Why its not work if i running it on windows 7?

You need to run the (hosting) App as Administrator. Opening a port for listening is a privileged operation.